# C++/CLI threading with static member functions

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli

I have a class called MCWrapper, from which I want to call a static member function as a thread to take in data from a socket.  I've been able to create an instance of the managed class in my console app and pass it data but now I'm hoping to clean things up and push as much as possible to the dll I'm building.

So MCWrapper has a member function receiveMessageThread of type static void.  How can I pass it a reference to the instance of the managed class and start it as a thread using the System::Threading methods?  From what I understand this is what I need to do to make it be able to access the other non-static member functions of MCWrapper (which is essentially a large storage class).  I've been playing around for a day now and keep getting stuck.

In the console app I create the managed class like so:

```
MCWrapper ^mc = gcnew MCWrapper();
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, when I ask a question I immediately find the answer.  Perhaps this will help someone.

Create the reference to the object you want:

```
MCWrapper^ mc = gcnew MCWrapper;
```

Start a thread that calls the member function as it starts.

```
Thread^ rThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(mc, MCWrapper::receiveMessageThread));
```

Then start the thread.

```
rThread->Start();
```

Pretty easy once you know.  Please let me know if anyone has a better way of doing this.

Cheers,

Comment: _As usual, when I ask a question I immediately find the answer._ I know this feeling :-)